# Why do apes still exist?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution

If we are evolved from apes, why don't all ape evolve and become human.

Or

> Why the today's ape stop evolving to become a human?

Comment: Because their environmental niches suit being apes.  Evolution does not have a goal.

Comment: Okay. But why is my question downvoted?

Comment: @jamesqf Why don't all apes evolve then?

Comment: Why do you think apes don't evolve?  Like any and all other creatures, they continuously evolve to become better suited to their environment, which is why there are about 20 species of living apes, each suited to their particular environments.  And I downvoted your question because I think it is pure creationist claptrap.  If it's not, the answer is pretty obvious: why do we have different species of cats, bears, equines, or any other group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to bother putting any references for this answer as all the information is a google search away.

**Humans did not evolve from apes.** Extant humans and apes developed from a common ancestor. One lineage from this common ancestor evolved and became apes. Another lineage went on to become humans.

Some study material [here](https://humanorigins.si.edu/education/introduction-human-evolution) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_evolution).

Answer (score -1):

Unless one can describe a "common ancestor", this phylogenetic knee jerk response begs the question. Humans evolved from animals not distinguishable taxonomically from apes. Phylogeneticists invoke the common ancestor explanation because their analysis is actually a form of cluster analysis, where groups of traits split dichotomously into smaller groups of traits. This is not a model of evolution.

Comment: OK, so what *is* a model of evolution?

Comment: Can you provide a link to explanations of alternate and feasible hypothesis?